# Match nucleotide position to sequence from fasta file

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I have list of positions:

```
chr1 1000
chr2 2000
chr3 4000
```

and would like to be able to transform those position in their nucleotide sequence giving a custom fasta file. Such as:

```
chr1 1000 A
chr2 2000 T
chr3 4000 G
```

Is there any already written tool in python that can do this job?

Comment: check [biopython](http://biopython.org/) You can easily read FASTA format and access elements of the sequence.

Comment: For future reference, there is also https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ where you can ask bioinformatics-specific questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the FASTA file  `chromosomes.fasta`:

```
>chr1
GATTACA
>chr2
ATTACGA
>chr3
GCCAACG
```

And the positions file `positions.txt`:

```
chr1 3

chr2 4

chr3 5
```

You can use the following code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
record_dict = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse('chromosomes.fasta', "fasta"))

chromosome_positions = {}
with open('positions.txt') as f:
    for line in f.read().splitlines():
        if line:
            chromosome, position = line.split()
            chromosome_positions[chromosome] = int(position)


for chromosome in chromosome_positions:
    seq = record_dict[chromosome]
    position = chromosome_positions[chromosome]
    base = seq[position]
    print chromosome, position, base
```

Which will output:

```
chr3 5 C
chr2 4 C
chr1 3 T
```

Note that Python uses [zero-based indexing](http://python-history.blogspot.be/2013/10/why-python-uses-0-based-indexing.html), so position `5` in `positions.txt` will give you the sixth base in the corresponding sequence.

Comment: This fails for aligned FASTA of course due to gaps, but it's probably fair to assume that's not the question being asked here